# Vue directives inside templates

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am quite new to vueJs, and I am trying to create something like a tab menu.
I have a dropdown navbar, each link creates a new tab, and this new tab is a Vue component.

I am trying to put a `v-on:click` directive in the created tab, but it does not call the function. In fact I get errors like

> "Property or method "removeTab" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render."

and

> "removeTab is not a function."

But `removeTab` is a function, and if I put the `v-on:click` in a static html tag it works. Am I doing something wrong, or is it impossible to have directives in dynamically loaded components?

Here is a simplified version of my code, just in order to show better what I am trying to explain. RemoveTab is just an alert, just to show when it works and when it does not.

HTML

```
<div  id="application">

  <button class="item" v-on:click="addTab()">Add Button</button>
  <button class="item" v-on:click="removeTab()">Remove</button>
  <br><br>


  <div >
    <tab v-for ="tab in tabs" :tab="tab"></tab>
  </div>
</div>


 <template id="tab-template">
   <button class="item">
     {{tab.nomeTab}} &nbsp; <div v-on:click="removeTab()">remove</div>
   </button>
</template>
```

JS

```
Vue.component('tab', {
  template: '#tab-template',
  props: ['tab']
});

new Vue({
  el: '#application',
  data:{
    newTab:'',
    tabs: [
      {nomeTab:'Home', contenutoTab:'ciao'},
    ]
  },
  methods:{
    addTab: function() {
      this.tabs.push({
        nomeTab: 'NewTab',
      });
    },

    removeTab: function () {
       alert("Here it works");
    }
  }
});
```

and here it is on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ggv57ne/2/).

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Leo is correct; essentially you are trying to call the `removeTab` method in your child, but the method is defined on your parent. The child does not have access to the methods on the parent directly.

In order to get your example working, since your parent will likely be managing the tabs, you will want to emit an event from your tabs and listen for the event in your parent.

```
<button class="item" v-on:click="$emit('remove-tab')">{{tab.nomeTab}} &nbsp; <div >remove</div></button>
```

And in the parent template

```
<tab v-for ="tab in tabs" :key="tab" :tab="tab" @remove-tab="removeTab"></tab>
```

And here is your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ggv57ne/3/) fixed.

Not also I added a `key` to your `v-for`. You should always use a `key` with `v-for`.

Answer (score 0):

Vue has isolated scope. You have `v-on:click="removeTab()"` in the template of your tab component, but it's not defined within the component.